# Angular DOM Elements that are not destroyed

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, dom, detach

I have been building an web application on Angular and I had an issue with the performance when I create dynamic elements trough a directive. I don't know how to clear up my old elements.

Here is an example what's going on exactly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-am1w1o

If you check the performance monitor, you will see that the DOM Nodes are increasing and I have no idea how to clear up them. any ideas :)

[image]

(I had issues with the previous example, but it is alright now)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the source code of your problem, a sample of the HTML being generated and explain how the components are interacting with each other.

Comment: Sorry,  I had issues with the stack blitz. Now the example is working.

Comment: Just more information, trying to use the Chrome Dev tools, I noticed that the number of DOM Nodes decrease everytime that I do a memory snapshot. 
Then the Performance monitor cannot be so reliable tool after all.
I'm trying to figure out with simple Javascript 
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length

but don't know if the detached elements are still around.

Comment: There is a forced garbage collection just before it takes the snapshot and that is the reason for the decrease in DOM nodes